# JPA table "sequence" does not exist

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

**Database:**

```
user_account
id(pk)
email
password
...

user_detail
id(pk fk)
name_first
name_last
...
```

**Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user_account")     
@SecondaryTable(name="user_detail", pkJoinColumns=@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn())
public class UserAccount implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2606506548742732094L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String tab;
    private String shortcut;
    private String setting;
    private Integer role;

    @Column(table="user_detail", name="name_first")
    private String nameFirst;
    @Column(table="user_detail", name="name_last")
    private String nameLast;
    @Column(table="user_detail")
    private String occupation;
    @Column(table="user_detail")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date birth;
    ....
}
```

**Action**

```
    try{
        EntityTransaction transaction = em.getTransaction();
        transaction.begin();
        em.persist(currentUser);

        transaction.commit();
    } catch (Exception e){
    }
```

**Error**

> INFO: [EL Warning]: 2012-01-06
>   18:45:46.77--ClientSession(17472935)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002]
>   (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504):
>   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal
>   Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table
>   'mazedb.sequence' doesn't exist Error Code: 1146 Call: UPDATE SEQUENCE
>   SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + ? WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?  bind => [2
>   parameters bound] Query: DataModifyQuery(name="SEQUENCE" sql="UPDATE
>   SEQUENCE SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + ? WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?")
>
> INFO: ERROR:  Internal Exception:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table
>   'mazedb.sequence' doesn't exist Error Code: 1146 Call: UPDATE SEQUENCE
>   SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + ? WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?  bind => [2
>   parameters bound] Query: DataModifyQuery(name="SEQUENCE" sql="UPDATE
>   SEQUENCE SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + ? WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?")

I tried the other way around, having two different entities merged by @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn but I got the same error.

Comment: Well, the message says that you need to have a sequence table. Why don't you create it?

Comment: But why would I need this table if is not supposed to be there?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If EclipseLink tries to access this table, that means that it's supposed to be there. `GenerationType.AUTO` means that EclipseLink chooses the most appropriate generation type for your database (MySQL). In this case, the choice is to use a table-based generator, which needs a table. See http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Entities/Ids/GeneratedValue.

If you don't want to use this strategy, choose another one.

Comment: The given link is dead.

Comment: I had to create the table so to save others googling time here's the SQL `CREATE TABLE SEQUENCE (SEQ_NAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, SEQ_COUNT DECIMAL(15), PRIMARY KEY (SEQ_NAME))`

Answer (score 6):

I had  never had this error before despite doing this kind of thing a hundred times.  I found this error was because I had a hibernate property for creating tables in the `persistence.xml` but was using EclipseLink:

It was:

```
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
```

I changed to the following to fix the error:

```
    <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>
    <!-- or just value="create-tables" -->
```

Comment: Worked for me, although I didn't have the first of the property defined in persistence.xml. Adding the suggest property took away the exception.

Answer (score 2):

This exception can occur even if you use `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)`!

From the [EclipseLink Wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Entities/Ids/GeneratedValue):

> **Note**: IDENTITY strategy is database specific and not supported on all database. IDENTITY is supported on Sybase, DB2, SQL Server, MySQL, Derby, JavaDB, Informix, SQL Anywhere, H2, HSQL, Access, and Postgres databases.

I changed the database server and client from MySQL to MariaDB which is not supported for `GenerationType.IDENTITY` as stated above.
So I had to add the following property to the `persistence.xml`:

```
<persistence ...
  <persistence-unit ...
  ...
  <properties>
    <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="MySQL"/>
  </properties>
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

`@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)` looks like a default value provided by IDE on entity creation. However, if you are using `org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider`, given the way it processes this annotation (leading to the exception being thrown), 
the simplest solution would be to just use `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)` instead.

Answer (score -1):

In the configuration file, `org.hibernate.dialect.oracle10gdialect` line can be forgotten. Indeed, `org.hibernate.dialect.mysqldialect` should be.